# Dynamically parsing files

Tags: go, go-templates

For parsing files i have setup a variable for template.ParseFiles and i currently have to manually set each file.

Two things:

How would i be able to walk through a main folder and a multitude of subfolders and automatically add them to ParseFiles so i dont have to manually add each file individually?

How would i be able to call a file with the same name in a subfolder because currently I get an error at runtime if i add same name file in ParseFiles.

```go
var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "index.html", // main file
    "subfolder/index.html" // subfolder with same filename errors on runtime
    "includes/header.html", "includes/footer.html",
))


func main() {
    // Walk and ParseFiles
    filepath.Walk("files", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            // Add path to ParseFiles


        }
        return
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    render(w, "index.html")
}

func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To walk a directory looking for files see: http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk or http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#New and http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Parse

As for your other question ParseFiles uses the base name of the file as the template name which results in a collision in your template. You have two choices

1. Rename the file.
2. use `t := template.New("name of your choice")` to create an initial template

   1. Use the walk function you already have started and call `t.Parse("text from file")` for each template file. You'll have to open and read the contents of the template files yourself to pass in here.

Edit: Code example.

```
func main() {
    // Walk and ParseFiles
    t = template.New("my template name")
    filepath.Walk("files", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            // Add path to ParseFiles
            content := ""
            // read the file into content here
            t.Parse(content)
        }
        return
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Totally getting there. I set the var templates at the top outside the main function because in a later function i need to use that to templates.ExecuteTemplate(). in your above example how would you call an individual template if your just adding content?

Answer (score 0):

So basically i set New("path name i want").Parse("String from read file") while walking through the folders.

```go
var templates = template.New("temp")

func main() {
    // Walk and ParseFiles
    parseFiles()

    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

//////////////////////
// Handle Functions //
//////////////////////
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    render(w, "index.html")
    render(w, "subfolder/index.html")
}

////////////////////////
// Reusable functions //
////////////////////////
func parseFiles() {
    filepath.Walk("files", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            filetext, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
        if err != nil {
                return err
        }
        text := string(filetext)
            templates.New(path).Parse(text)
        }
        return nil
    })
}

func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```